# Repeating forms in django form wizard

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I've created a form wizard in django which starts with a form which the user can enter their details (name, age etc.) into.

The wizard then goes on to some other forms I need.

Now I want to expand the wizard so that the user can add as many other user details as they like.

So basically, it needs to be something like:-

User details -> Do you want to add more?

If yes -> User details

If no -> Next form

I also need the user to be able to edit previous user details or remove previous user details entirely.

I've tried adding a load of conditional forms for the user details, which are switched on or off, depending on whether the user replied Yes to the "add more" question. However, all of the user details form fields have the same name so they overwrite each other. Also, this seems like a hack to me.

So what's the "proper" way to do this? Put simply, how do I conditionally repeat forms based on user input as the wizard progresses?

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use django formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/ that way the user can add as many as they like.. However I am not sure how that works with the Wizard thought because of the management form.. You can try it and return feedback :)

Comment: Ah yes, I did think of that - however, what I forgot to mention was that, for each extra user, there is another (quite long) form which needs to be filled in.

So it's "user" -> "user info" -> "user" -> "user info" etc. which makes it much more complex and means that formsets no longer suit the problem.